# epydoc: Blocks of fixed-width text

Tags: markup, fixed-width, epydoc

I have written a software component that relies on a configuration file. For clarity, I want to document the structure of the configuration file by adding an example file in the docstring of the relevant class. For obvious reasons, it should appear in fixed-width font.

The only way I know is adding `>>>` before each line, which is bad  because doctest might think this is a Python code segment and lose its wits. Moreover, it looks really ugly:

`>>>` [db]

`>>>` port = 5432

`>>>` name = adam_db

`...`

What I really want is:

> [db]
>
> port=5432
>
> name=adam_db
>
> ...

In a fixed-width font.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [Literal Block](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epydoc.html#literal-blocks) option.